# Gradle nested project configuration

Tags: java, gradle, nested, build.gradle, project

I'm a bit confused about setting up the build script for a nested project

I've written a simple test repo here https://github.com/814k31/TestGradle

Essentially I am writing a wrapper for a module and need that wrapper to be included in a larger project, however I'm having trouble importing the module in the wrapper when it is used within a larger project

Dependency Chain

`app imports OneDeep
 OneDeep imports TwoDeep`

Directory structure:

`app
oneDeep
    twoDeep
       build.gradle
    build.gradle
build.gradle
settings.gradle`

The master branch in the test repo is written how I should expect it to work

There is also another branch where I've tweaked the settings.gradle to work, though it feels like I shouldn't do that...

Any suggestions on how to get oneDeep (the wrapper) to import twoDeep (the module)?

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You don't describe the error you get, but if we execute your example from the master branch in your repo, we get following error:

```
> Project with path ':twoDeep' could not be found in project ':oneDeep'.
```

This problem comes from the way you reference project 'twoDeep' from project 'oneDeep' script:

```
dependencies {
    compile project(':twoDeep')  // <== this won't work: there is no project with absolute path ":twoDeep"

    // compile project('twoDeep')         //  <== use relative path to reference sub-project 'twoDeep' from project 'oneDeep'
    // compile project(':oneDeep:twoDeep') // <=  using absolute path will work as well
   }
```

So you must either use relative path ( => 'twoDeep' ) or absolute path ( => ':oneDeep:twoDeep') when referencing subproject 'twoDeep' from project 'oneDeep'.

From [Project DSL documentation](https://docs.gradle.org/current/dsl/org.gradle.api.Project.html#org.gradle.api.Project:project(java.lang.String)):

> Project project(String path) : 
>   Locates a project by path. If the path is relative, it is interpreted relative to this project.

See also [Project and task paths](https://docs.gradle.org/current/userguide/multi_project_builds.html#sec:project_and_task_paths)  (but it's not clearly stated there what is the expected syntax for "relative" paths)

Comment: Thank you!

Yes that was the error I was getting


I had tried `compile project(':oneDeep:twoDeep')` a few times however was messing with other config setting so must have wrecked it with something else


Tried it just now and it worked fine